# PostgreSQL, what does the ending after FROM stand for?

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias

For example

```
select * from table1 rel
```

what does `rel` mean?

also

```
select * from ( select id from table1) main where (data)principal.
```

what does `main` and `principal` mean? they are not keyword and anything.

Comment: main and rel are table alias

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES

Comment: I've never seen `(data)principal` before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL is assuming that "rel" is the alias for "table1", once the reserved word "AS" is not required. Same for the second case.

Cheers

Nikao

Answer (score 0):

it's an alias, have a look at the documentation: 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

or here from postgresql: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES